# Column editing in gvim in multiple files

Tags: vim, scripting

I am a newbie to scripting and I want to do column editing in a generated file in gvim.

The problem is i know how to do it in a single file(by entering into visual block mode in gvim) but i have to do the same editing for numerous files and it is not possible to open each file and performing the required operation in each file.

Does any scripting language provides a way to do so?

edit 1: I have to replace the entire column with another text.

Comment: You can do column replacement with `\%c`  (see `:help \%c`). Consider providing sample input in your questoin and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It woul be great to se the input and output examples, but for now I woul sugest something like:

```
vim *.txt
:argdo exe "normal wciWnewword"
:argdo update

w ........ jump to the seccond word
ciW ..... change inner big word
update save changes
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, make **a backup of your files** before trying any of this.

It is hard to say how the content of your files looks like from the description, but assuming it is space separated file, to change the first column (first word in each line) using a `vim`, without manually opening each file try this from shell prompt:

```sh
for fname in * ; do vim -N -c ":%s/\v^\w+/NEWTEXT/g|:wq" "${fname}" ; done
```

where:

- `*` is shell glob and means "all files". If your files do not reside in separate directory, or you don't want affect them all, provide list like `for fname in file1 file2 file3...`
- `NEWTEXT` is the substitution text.
- `-c` executes `vim` command at startup
- `:` enters the command mode in `vim`
- `%` makes whole file an object of an operation
- `s/REGEXP/SUBSTITUTION/g` means insert SUBSTITUTION in place of each string matching REGEX
- `\v` makes escapes and special characters in `vim` regular expressions behave like in POSIX regex.
- `^` means "from beginning of line"
- `\w` means "any word character"
- `+` means "one or more of preceding characters"
- `|` separates `vim` commands (it is *not* a shell pipe)
- `:wq` saves changed file and exits `vim`

Using `vim` this way may not be the best idea.
Consider using e.g. `sed` instead

```sh
for fname in * ; do 
  sed -ir "s/^\w+/NEWTEXT/g" "${fname}"
done
```

-`r` flag tells `sed` to use regexp
- `i` tells it to change file in place, i.e. no output redirection needed.